# Cannot logon to POP server on my VPS or recieve emails

Tags: email, vps, webmin

I recently purchased an unmanaged VPS to host my business websites, however I am struggling to get the email accounts working as I have only ever had experience with shared hosting.

The VPS is running CentOS and I have Webmin/Virtualmin installed. I have added my domain, which is lyke.org.uk, and that is working OK. However, when I've added a user and tried to access their email account using Apple Mail, I've been able to establish a SMTP connection but I've not been able to login using POP.

Furthermore, I've set up squirrelmail and I can send an email to any email address from there  but I haven't recieved any that I have sent to that email address from other accounts.

I would very much appreciate any help or suggestions as  I am completely new to VPS and web hosting without Plesk or cPanel.

Comment: Is Dovecot IMAP/POP3 installed? BTW- some will argue, but I have had good luck with VirtualMin.

Comment: @closetnoc Yes, Dovecat, and Postfix is installed

Comment: Try this to test: http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/pop.shtml. I seem to remember that Dovecot was a bit fiddlie at first but has worked fine for years with issues- so it is worth it in the end.

Comment: @closetnoc Just tried that test and it is working fine. I can login to the server using Telnet with no issues. What could the problem be?

Comment: Interesting. If you can log in, then I would say the problem is on the client side. Check that your client(s) are using POP3 (you just tested POP3) an not IMAP which may be a default these days. Once done, you may want to check into IMAP for the future. I still use POP3, but I never go over the Internet for e-mail.

Comment: Well, the email client is definately using POP but I have just tested using IMAP and the results seem strange. It downloaded the one email on the server but still will not send. Conversely, that email is telling me that another email address I set up on the domain doesn't exist (as I tried to send an email to it from the webmail, which does send emails)

Comment: Interesting. I would also advise checking Dovecot, Networking and Protocols to make sure that the defaults are selected and each protocol is selected. On User and Logon Options, is clear text selected? Same with the client. Double check that it is POP3 and not POP. It may be that the client or server is using one of the MD5 options and the other is not. MD5 is preferred over clear text, but just to get you connected, you may want to try it.

Comment: @closetnoc I have just had a check with Outlook 2010 rather than Apple Mail, and guess what, it is working! Well... I can succesfully send a test email, but when I attempt to email somebody else from the account I immediately get an Undeliverable email with the server error `554... Relay access denied`. Does this bring us any closer to the problem?

Comment: Actually, two separate issues. The 554 Relay access denied is where an SMTP server tries to relay e-mail through another SMTP server without relay access set-up. Relay is not normal and probably not what you want. Your SMTP server should be sending directly to the addressee's SMTP server and not trying to relay through another server. VirtualMin, Postfix Mail Server, General Options, Send outgoing mail via host- should be set to deliver directly. As for the Apple Mail, I have no clue. It has to be a setting somewhere in the client.

Comment: I'm going to push the Apple Mail issue aside for the moment and work with Outlook as this is the client that I know best. The SMTP server was and is however set to directly deliver as you say and the issue is still occuring

Comment: Under VirtualMin, Postfix Mail Server, Virtual Domains, Domain mapping lookup tables- is map specifications = (something like) hash:/etc/postfix/virtual? Also check Mail Aliases- Alias databases used by the local delivery agent- and Alias databases built by "newaliases" command- map specifications = hash:/etc/aliases (each). Did you use Virtualmin Virtual Servers to set up your virtual servers or use something else? I have to admit I goofed it up the first time. You will want to use Virtualmin Virtual Servers for configuration of site stuff almost exclusively.

Comment: I have checked the settings you mentioned and they are all as you say they should be. And yes, I created a Virtual Server using VirtualMin and managed everything from there

Comment: Huh. I am plum outta ideas. At least for now. Does the 554 relay access denied happen for all users sending e-mail (different computers too)? If not, then it is a user access issue (client). If so, then it is a server configuration issue. http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html - general. http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html access configuration. *Check the e-mail client to see if SMTP authorization is enabled?* Outlook in the past would not enable this by default. I would place a bet on this one! (if I had any money that is...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13968/discussion-between-andy-and-closetnoc)

Comment: going there now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have posted this answer a while ago as thanks to @closetnoc I actually managed to get the mail server working correctly the same night I posted this question. As memory serves, the following was the solution to my issue.

I had changed the username format for the mail usernames under 'System Settings'->'Server Templates'->'Mail for domain' to be username@domain instead of username.domain which was the root of the login issue. The `saslauthd` daemon that is responsible for sending email securely must be running with the `-r` flag to accept usernames in this format. For CentOS, which is what my VPS is running, the method to make `saslauthd` run with the -r flag by default can be found on the following forum topic: https://www.virtualmin.com/node/15570

It took me more time to resolve this on my server as I had changed other settings in Webmin in trying to get it to work. The moral is that if you use Virtualmin, you should very rarely need to go into Webmin and alter settings (especially for mail) as this can often cause more issues and is unnecessary.

One other complication I had was that the domain was also being hosted on a shared hosting server and even though the domain was pointing to the name servers of the VPS, the shared hosting server still had the DNS records enabled for the domain. This caused a conflict when I tried to send emails from other domains that were also hosted on the shared hosting server and meant that the emails were not being delivered. I simply disabled the domain in Plesk on my shared hosting server to resolve this.